# Jenkins: Trigger different builds depending on different actions in bitbucket project

Tags: jenkins

I have a bitbucket project for which I need to setup Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery. I need to trigger different build projects on jenkins depending on which branch the code was pushed into bitbucket. Also, I want to be able to trigger different builds on jenkins when a pull request is created. Right now I could find the bitbucket plugin but it seems to have only one url that I can provide and inside the jenkins project I can see that I can provide the branch regex. So, this can solve the purpose of executing different builds when changes are pushed to different branches. However, I am not sure how can I trigger a build only when a pull request is created for a particular branch? I mean there needs to be separate build triggered when a commit is pushed to say `dev` branch and another project triggered when someone creates/updates a pull request for `dev` branch.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something the [multibranch-pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/) project would solve. Here you can have different pipelines for each branch in the repository.